# Heatmap for confusion matrix that is sensitive to the distance to the left diagonal line and the magnitude

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, heatmap, confusion-matrix

I have five classes: Q0_10, Q10_20, Q20_30, Q30_40, and Q40_50.   Q10_20 for example, means that the percentile rank of the account lies somewhere between 10th percentile and 20th percentile.

With some classification techniques for a number of accounts, I predicted the classes and got the confusion matrix as follows:

```
 Predicted  Q0_10  Q10_20  Q20_30  Q30_40  Q40_50
 Actual
 Q0_10        5       6       0       4       5
 Q10_20       1       7       4       1       0
Q20_30        5       3       2       0       1
Q30_40        4       2       5       2       0
Q40_50        0       1       2       1       7
```

One way of doing heatmap is as follows:

```
array = [[5,6,0,4,5], 
    [1,7,4,1,0], 
    [5,3,2,0,1], 
    [4,2,5,2,0], 
    [0,1,2,1,7]] 


df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, index = [i for i in "ABCDE"],
              columns = [i for i in "ABCDE"])
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True)
```

But this doesn’t give exactly what I want. I want to apply two criteria.

One is that the closer values are to the left diagonal line, the better. For example, when the actual class is Q10_20, we have 1 account classified as Q0_10 and 1 account classified as Q30_40.  For me, the color of account that is predicted as Q0_10 should be better than that which is classified as Q30_40 because it’s further away.

Second is that the magnitude of the number of accounts. For example, 1 account is actually Q10_20 and predicted as Q0_10 and  4 accounts are also actually Q10_20 but predicted as Q20_30.  Here, Q0_10 is the same distance to Q10_20 as Q20_30. So the color coding from that perspective is not different. But since more accounts are predicted as Q20_30, the color should emphasize on the magnitude of 4.

Comment: I tried to find a solution according to your description - are you looking for something like this https://prnt.sc/TlC0IgRIkgoR? If so, I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = np.array([[5,6,0,4,5], 
                  [1,7,4,1,0], 
                  [5,3,2,0,1], 
                  [4,2,5,2,0], 
                  [0,1,2,1,7]])

classes = ['Q0_10', 'Q10_20', 'Q20_30', 'Q30_40', 'Q40_50']


# Normalized confusion matrix
cm = array / array.sum(axis = 1, keepdims = True)

# Color map
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, as_cmap = True)

# Seaborn Heatmap
sns.heatmap(cm, cmap = cmap, center = 0, annot = array, fmt = 'd',
            xticklabels = classes, yticklabels = classes, annot_kws = {'size': 12})


plt.xlabel('Predicted Class', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Actual Class', fontsize=14)
plt.title('Confusion Matrix', fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

Your implementation is missing a lot - you first have to create a normalized confusion matrix on top of which you then add your color map. My suggestion above is pretty basic and may be expanded to  your wishes.

The result of the heat map is as you described:

[image]

Comment: However, there is something that might be missing.  If you look at actual class Q10_20. one account was predicted as Q0_10 and one account is predicted as class Q30_40.

Class Q30_40 is further from class Q10_20 that class Q0_10 is. Thus, its color should be worse. But they have the same color